# R: cut by date and grouping by ID with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with with a list of actors uniquely identified by `id` doing things on a `date`. There is no limit to number of things done by an `actor` on a particular `date`.

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(28100)
df.in <- data.table(id = sample(1:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
                    date = sample(2001:2012, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Now I want to summarise my dataset finding the number of occurrences for each of the intervals of the following sequence

```
sequence <- seq(2000, 2012, 4)

df.out1 <- as.data.frame(table(cut(df.in$date, breaks = sequence)))

df.out1
# Var1 Freq
# 1 (2000,2004]   35
# 2 (2004,2008]   27
# 3 (2008,2012]   38
```

All good. But now instead of counting the occurrences I would like to count the number of actors active in each interval, that is with one or more occurrences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df.in[, interv := cut(date, sequence)][, .(Actors = length(unique(id))), by = interv]
#        interv Actors
#1: (2000,2004]     10
#2: (2008,2012]      9
#3: (2004,2008]     10
```

In case you are using the development version 1.9.5 from GitHub you could use `uniqueN()` instead of `length(unique())`.