# Bin Range in R- Max and Min logic for Range of frequencies for each group

Tags: r

I have the below dataset where i would like to create range of frequencies for each group.

I am able to create the same, however can't able to customize the size of the bin for each group.

Below is how my data looks like.

```
Date, Group, Sales
Jan-17, A , 1000
Feb-17, A , 1200
Mar-17, A , 700
Apr-17, A , 2000
May-17, A , 1800
Jan-17, B , 5000
Feb-17, B , 5800
Mar-17, B , 6800
Apr-17, B , 7000
May-17, B , 6000
```

As you can see, "A" group lies between 700 and 2000, while "B" group lies between 5000 and 7000. My current code assign all the group based on the same bin size, however i would like customize the bin size based on the max-min divided by 5 for each group,i.e. here i want to create 5 different bins for each group.

Hence for A i want to create 5 bins for size 280 [(2000-700)/5 => 280], where starting should be [700-980],[980-1260],[1260-1540]. Similar approach for group B. I would like to apply the approach for max and min, as mentioned above for all the group.

Also, it would be great, if there i some way where i can map the Bin ([700-980], to my existing dataframe. Not sure if that is possible.

Below is my existing code with a standard bin size range.

```
df %>%
group_by(Group) %>%
mutate(freq=cut(Sales, breaks=seq(0,8000,by=50), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `dplyr` and grouping by `Group` before using `cut`...

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
              mutate(bin=cut(Sales,
                             breaks=seq(min(Sales),max(Sales),length.out = 6),
                             include.lowest=TRUE,
                             dig.lab=50))

df2
   Date   Group Sales bin        
 1 Jan-17 A      1000 (960,1220] 
 2 Feb-17 A      1200 (960,1220] 
 3 Mar-17 A       700 [700,960]  
 4 Apr-17 A      2000 (1740,2000]
 5 May-17 A      1800 (1740,2000]
 6 Jan-17 B      5000 [5000,5400]
 7 Feb-17 B      5800 (5400,5800]
 8 Mar-17 B      6800 (6600,7000]
 9 Apr-17 B      7000 (6600,7000]
10 May-17 B      6000 (5800,6200]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried it, however it's still somehow taking the overall range rather than picking range for the group in scope. Not sure why the same is happening.

Comment: Is there any other alternative apart from the existing code from dplyr package?

Comment: Not sure why it would not work for you - it did for me.  I think `cut` is the standard way to do this sort of thing, either in `dplyr` or otherwise, although see this question for an approach using `data.table` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375100/r-cut-by-date-and-grouping-by-id-with-data-table.

Comment: @Jay - have you possibly loaded other packages in addition to `dplyr`

Comment: yes.. there are multiple packages currently, shall i install only dplyr while running this code, and remove the others